# LiipImagineBundle imagine_filter not working

Tags: symfony, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, liipimaginebundle, gaufrette

I have a problem with the imagine_filter that works in one page and not in the others even if I use it exactly the same way with the same photo.

In the first page, where my filter works, I have this src:
               http://myserver.com/media/cache/shooting/photo_preview/75/55cb71cc8ba26-00001.jpg

However, on the page where the filter doesn't work, I have this src:

```
:///media/cache/shooting/photo_preview/75/55cb71cc8ba26-00001.jpg
```

Has anybody already have a problem like that?

Moreover, the first src only works on app.php and not on app_dev.php.

On my application, I'm using Gaufrette to upload photos to S3 and then Liip to apply the filters. The cache is on my server. This is my configuration:

```
"liip/imagine-bundle": "1.3.*@dev",
"knplabs/gaufrette": "0.1.*",
"knplabs/knp-gaufrette-bundle": "0.1.*@dev",
"aws/aws-sdk-php": "2.8.*@dev",
```

<--- The services --->

```
services:
    mycompany.aws_s3.client:
            class:                    Aws\S3\S3Client
            factory_class:       Aws\S3\S3Client
            factory_method:   'factory'
            arguments:
                -
                    key:      %amazon_aws_key%
                    secret:   %amazon_aws_secret_key%
                    region:   %amazon_aws_region%

    mycompany.liip_imagine.binary.loader.stream.shooting:
          class: '%liip_imagine.binary.loader.stream.class%'
          arguments:
            - 'gaufrette://shooting/'
          tags:
            - { name: 'liip_imagine.binary.loader', loader: 'stream.shooting' }
```

<--- Gaufrette --->

```
knp_gaufrette:
    adapters:
        shooting:
            aws_s3:
                service_id:     mycompany.aws_s3.client
                bucket_name:    %amazon_s3_bucket%
                options:
                    directory:  shooting
    filesystems:
        shooting:
            adapter:    shooting
            alias:      shooting_filesystem
    stream_wrapper:     ~
```

<--- Liip --->

```
liip_imagine:
    resolvers:
        default:
            web_path: ~
        shooting:
            web_path:
                cache_prefix:   /media/cache/shooting
    controller:
        filter_action:      mycompany_imagine.controller:filterAction
    filter_sets:
        photo_preview:
            data_loader:    stream.shooting
            cache:          shooting
            quality:        50
            filters:
                upscale: { min: [690, 690] }
                thumbnail: { size: [690, 690], mode: outbound}
```

<--- Twig --->

```
<img src="{{ photo.imagepath | imagine_filter('photo_preview') }}" alt="">
```

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer on Github. I just needed to change my resolver:

https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle/issues/203